# struct syntax in ansi c with commas and only one type declaration for multiple fields

Tags: c

I've run across such a definition of struct in ansi C:

```
struct My_data {
    int a,
     b,
     c,
     d;
};
```

and structs created this way function perfectly. My question is if this is legal syntax specifically in ansi C. I couldn't find any such information in K&R.

Comment: yes, it is legal.

Comment: C11 standard §6.7.2.1 "Structure and union specifiers" has a rule where one of the alternatives is: _struct-declarator-list:
struct-declarator-list `,` struct-declarator_, where a simple name such as `a` is one possibility for a _struct-declarator_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's legal.

It's equivalent to:

```
struct My_data {
    int a, b, c, d;
};
```

or

```
struct My_data {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};
```

or even

```
struct My_data {
    int arr[4]; /* An array of 4 ints. This isn't strictly equivalent - but functionally equivalent */
};
```

Specifically to your question, see the grammar of structs in [C11 draft, 6.7.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1) (and also that of [C11, 6.7.6, declaratrors](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6)).